# How to handle Tridion related questions on sites other than this one

Tags: discussion

Since this site is still in Beta, we don't have an option to automatically ask for migration of new [tridion](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tridion) related questions which pop up on Stack Exchange and Server Fault etc.

I've seen a lot of you leaving a comment suggesting to post the question here, since they will get a broader audience, which is very true of course.

However I think we could approach it a little differently, if you see a [tridion](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tridion) related question on another site which obviously belongs here, I suggest you flag it for moderator attention and ask in the comment box there if the question can be moved to http://tridion.stackexchange.com because it is a better fit over there.

If then you leave a comment on the question, that you asked it to be migrated, the OP will see that his question will be migrated too, so it doesn't come as a surprise.

It can take up to a few hours for the actual migration to happen, depending how busy the moderators on the site are. In the mean time, you can just continue with answering the question, or leaving other comments on it requesting for more information, since all those will automatically be migrated too. And at some point the question will appear here on our site (without us getting duplicates all over the internet).

Similar, if you see that a question is asked on here as well as on another Stack Exchange site, you should flag those questions for closure being a duplicate (on another site).

Comment: Good point. Just flagged one :)

Comment: +One to #OneCommunity